# Filter only duplicated rows based on condition

Tags: r, dataframe, filter, tidyverse, slice

In the data below, I want to filter the duplicated participants (Ana, Paul) based on their answer to *Q40*. Participants should have answered only "NoPlan" or "Plan", but sometimes they've answered both. I want to keep **only** the rows in each the *duplicated* participants have answered "Plan"

- The data is:

```
  ID     Q40   
  <chr>  <chr> 
1 Maria  Plan  
2 Joseph Plan  
3 Cyntia NoPlan
4 Ana    NoPlan   ## first noPlan
5 Paul   Plan  ## first Plan
6 Ana    Plan  ## then, Plan 
7 Paul   NoPlan ## then, noPlan
```

- Desired Output:

```
  ID     Q40   
  <chr>  <chr> 
1 Maria  Plan  
2 Joseph Plan  
3 Cyntia NoPlan
5 Paul   Plan  
6 Ana    Plan
```

- I was doing it manually, like this:

```
df %>% 
  filter(Q40 %in% c('noPlan', 'Plan')) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  distinct()

then I was removing manually the duplicated ones with (slice()) and their corresponding position.
```

*QUESTION*

*1:* How can I dinamically remove the rows **only** of the **duplicated** participants in *ID* (who answered "noPlan" and "plan" at the same time), keeping only their "Plan" row? I'm sure this is easy to do with `tidyverse` , but I'm struggling with it. I really need a `tidyverse` approach.

Important note:

*1* I *don't* want to filter all "NoPlan" rows, I only want to filter the "Plan" rows of the participants who have answered both NoPlan AND Plan. Only the duplicated ones, not the whole sample.

*2* I don't want to keep only the first row such as with `distinc()` , I want to be able to set the condition myself (in this case, to filter "NoPlan" from the duplicated participants

*3* I cannot use `distinct(starwars, pick(contains("color")))` because this would remove "NoPlan" from all participants and I need to filter only the duplicated ones

- data:

```
structure(list(ID = c("Joseph", "Cyntia", "Paul", "Ana", "Paul", 
"Maria", "Ana"), Q40 = c("Plan", "NoPlan", "Plan", "Plan", "NoPlan", 
"Plan", "NoPlan")), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 2):

`?duplicated` should aid you here:

```
dat %>%
    filter(!((duplicated(ID) | duplicated(ID, fromLast=TRUE)) & Q40 == "NoPlan"))
```

Or in base R speak:

```
dat[with(dat, !((duplicated(ID) | duplicated(ID, fromLast=TRUE)) & Q40 == "NoPlan")),]
```

Comment: thank you, @thelatemail! Would you explain me, please, the logic inside ```filter()``` ? Btw, I'm getting this warning: Caused by warning in `(duplicated(ID) | duplicated(ID, fromLast = TRUE)) & Q40 == "semPlanejamento"`:
! longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

Comment: The logic is: find all duplicated records using two `duplicated` statements so that *all* records with a duplicate are flagged, not just the first record. Then also look for those records that are `'Noplan'` as well. Remove those records finally `!`. That warning should not be occurring. It doesn't with your provided example data, and indicates you will probably get the wrong result in your actual dataset. I'd double check you are referencing the right variables.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you'd prefer a `tidyverse` answer, but here's a base R solution using the split-operate-recombine approach. You split by `ID`; in subsets with multiple rows, select the rows with "Plan" in `Q40`; then use `do.call("rbind", ...)` to put the remaining rows back together.

```
dat <- structure(list(ID = c("Joseph", "Cyntia", "Paul", "Ana", "Paul", 
"Maria", "Ana"), Q40 = c("Plan", "NoPlan", "Plan", "Plan", "NoPlan", 
"Plan", "NoPlan")), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))

do.call("rbind", lapply(split(dat, dat$ID), function(x) {

  if(nrow(x) > 1) {

    x[x$Q40 == "Plan",]

  } else {

    x

  }

}))
```

And here's what that produces:

```
  ID     Q40   
* <chr>  <chr> 
1 Ana    Plan  
2 Cyntia NoPlan
3 Joseph Plan  
4 Maria  Plan  
5 Paul   Plan
```

Comment: Thank you, @ulfelder! yeah, I really need a ```tidyverse``` approach to deal with the bigger dataset, do you have any ideas?

Comment: There's no reason that tidyverse solutions would do better than base with big data.